# Run Hive Query and Turn off computer

Tags: hive

How do I set up a Hive query to be able to continue running even after I turn off the computer?

```
hive -e "select session_skey, visitor_nkey, purchaseid, session_seq_num, hit_dt_1, hit_dt_ts, hit_elapsed_time,split(page_url,'/')[2], split(page_url,'/')[3], split(page_url,'/')[4],split(page_url,'cm_src=')[1],page_url from omn_prod_etl.web_fct_hit where hit_dt_1 >= '2018-11-05' and hit_dt_1 <= '2018-01-05' and page_url like '%ewd.com/products/%cm_src%' and data_source_skey= 'gobli'" | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/^/g' > /data/archive/hit_PR4.csv
```

Comment: Could you please specify how exactly you run hive: local mode or on cluster? The computer you run the query and computer you want to turn off, are they the same? If not, then adding ampersand `&` at the end of command you wrote will do the trick.

Comment: @serge_k I run it through putty

Comment: In that case just add ampersand & at the end of the command you wrote. This will make your command run as background process.